# Can get_line directly fill an std::vector<std::string>?

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I want to read a file line by line and dispatch the read lines to distinct std::vector(s) so that I could process these lines in parallel. Something like this (not even coded)

```
int nb_threads = 4;
std::vector my_vectors[nb_threads];
int count_lines = 0;
std::string line;
while (getline(my_stream, line)) {
    my_vectors[count_lines % nb_threads].push_back(line);   
    count_lines++
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the copy of `line` into `my_vectors[.]` so that `getline` would directly fill the vectors ?

Comment: I *think* `.push_back(std::move(line));` will steal the internal character buffer, rather than cost another allocation.

Comment: It seems you thought right, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use `std::move`
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: My teacher always said the weakness of the stl was that you have to copy the data into the containers...it seems he wasn't all that right. Thanks.

Comment: He was until November 2011. It's new (-ish).

Comment: November? What the hell am I talking about? [It was approved in August and published in September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11).

Answer (score 2):

Moving from `line` is the way to go here. Pre C++11, you could `push_back` an empty string and then read in it:

```
while(true) {
    size_t i = count_lines % nb_threads;
    my_vectors[i].push_back("");   
    if (!getline(my_stream, my_vectors[i].back())) {
        my_stream[i].pop_back();
        break;
    } 
    count_lines++;
}
```

Comment: I thought of pushing an empty string too.